# chat functionality on php application

Tags: php, zend-framework, dojo, chat, comet

SO has lot many questions of this type but not able to find correct solution. May be I am missing anything.

I am struggling from last few days for finding better option for Chat service.
Following thing I have to keep in mind before using any option..

- It should be OS independent
- Installation should be easy
- Opensource so that can be modify as per requirement.
- Lightweight
- Chat Client should be customizable and lightweight
- File Sharing, Private Chat, Group Chat, emotions should be there.
- Chat should not allow user to connect with other outsider chat servers like gmail, AOL, etc..

I have developed chat service using Openfire server as chat server and Jetty applet as client.
But this applet is not as userfriendly and need to work a lot to make it look like gmail chat or facebook chat..
Also I am going to use Zend framework, PHP, MySQL, Apache server. And server OS could be windows or Linux.

Here are few more questions...

- Is there way to use openfire server as chat server with some other javascript/AJAX/Dojo as Client?
- How we can use XAMPP-BOSH for Chat service? Is this XAMPP is related to XAMPP server of apache, PHP, etc...?
- How we can use Dojo.io.cometd library for chat?

Comment: I am now stucked while integrating jsjac with openfire and ijab with openfire. I am trying both options. I tried openfire 3.6.4 but found http-binding working issue. so I switched to openfire 3.4.1 so I am getting 401 non-authorized error.

Comment: solved partially. I used openfire 3.4.1 with jsjac and able to communicate on my local machine in different browser with different user. but as compare to ijab this is basic one.

Comment: Finally I am done with all setup on both openfire 3.6.4 and 3.4.1 server with ijab client. but I am still not able to create groups and File sharing .... And found some bugs on which I need to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have set openfire http-bind port to 8181 previously 7070.

Following changes i have done in ijab_config.js

```
xmpp:{ 
domain:"ipaddress", 
http_bind:"/http-bind/", 
host:"ipaddress:8181", 
port:5222, 
server_type:"Openfire", 
muc_servernode:"ipaddress",
...
}
```

and following will go to .htaccess file which will be placed in htdocs

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 
Options +MultiViews 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
      RewriteEngine On 
      RewriteRule http-bind/ http://ipaddress:8181/http-bind  [P] 
</IfModule>
```

Here ipaddress can be replace with localhost or domain name.

Answer (score 1):

Consider [AjaxIM](http://ajax.im). A colleague of mine developed it. There's no PHP aspect (there was, but it is no longer supported), but the front-end is entirely written in JavaScript and the back-end uses Node.js. This is very fast and should be relatively portable. I do not know whether it supports things like file sharing or group chat, though I do know that it does allow user-to-user communication.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this option also but found this is very much basic and this is at evolution stage so for enhancement i will find difficulty in future. But still they have done nice work. Will keep track there work.